# Angular: Couldn't resolve original symbol for ..."@angular/core/core.d.ts"

Tags: angular, typescript, tfs, command-line-interface

I've been beating my head around this for days. My work place has a project on TFS.  I download the project and run the following cli commands to modify the application to my environment.

`cd` to `.\ClientApp`

```
npm install 
npm install --save jquery popper.js moment bootstrap@4.0.0 @angular/material @angular/cdk ajv @fortawesome/fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid @angular/material-moment-adapter @angular/cdk@5.2.4 @angular/material@5.2.4 @angular/material-moment-adapter@5.2.4
```

I get the error

> Error in error: Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/debug/debug_node from D:/src/Expenser/ClientApp/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts aaaaat D:\src\Expenser\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:29542.....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjFQ5.png)

If I have a co worker zip the folder and give it to me it works fine.  But this is not a real solution.  I have tons of projects here and I need to be able to download these deals from TFS and go.  I should not have to hunt through file systems and cli commands to figure out what to do or why it doesn't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdkWi.png)

Comment: First step: Try to isolate the problem. You say a co-worker can give you a copy of their repo and it works properly. Use a tool like Beyond Compare to look at the two side-by-side and identify differences. Chances are, that will give you the information you need to solve your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to get project files on your machine using  another account from TFS?

Comment: Hi ben, any update on this issue, have you figure it out?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I have the same error. As a result, I am unable to build to prod

Answer (score 3):

This should work fine.

Try installing the core in your local machine. Below is the command. Run it in your terminal.

```
----- npm install @angular/core
```

Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, the reason the zip file works and the source control doesn't work is because your source control is ignoring the files in the folders that contain the word "debug".

This explains the message:

> Error in error: Couldn't resolve original symbol for ./src/debug/debug_node

As the code for "debug_node" can't be found.

The fact that angular uses the word "debug" in folders all over the place is very annoying.  There may be other keywords that your source control is ignoring too.

I recommend using a file comparison tool such as "Beyond Compare" to see all the differences between what is in your source control and what you have from the zip file.